# partial() on python types?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, type-definition

I often use type hints to help document code & occasionally when the type signatures are too complex & repeatedly used I alias them like this:

```py
MyType = Dict[Tuple[int,...], float]  # ex: cluster & score.
```

Is there a way in python to parametrize type parts? A common use case is when I want to describe functions returning generators. For instance the `Generator[int, None, None]` notation works but the unused `None` details could be hidden in a new type.

Does there exists something like `partial` functions on types where we can "lock in" some of the sub type parameters? Or perhaps this is doable via `Generics`? Conceptually I'm thinking of something like this:

```py
MyGenType[int] = functools.partial(Generator, None, None) # pseudo code!
```

Answer (score 2):

This did it:

```py
from typing import Generator, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
MyGenType = Generator[T, None, None]

def fn(n: int) -> MyGenType[str]:
    return (str(_) for _ in range(n))

list(fn(3)) # ['0', '1', '2']
```

Comment: In Python 3.12 and later there's [syntactic sugar](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) for this: `type MyGenType[T] = Generator[T, None, None]`.